# "Dependencies not met" complaint for example given in airflow docs

Tags: airflow

Following the airflow demo tutorial given in the docs (https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/tutorial.html#recap) (just a started using airflow for trial test), I notice that there are initial complaints about 'unmet dependencies' for certain tasks when running backfill `airflow backfill tutorial -s 2015-06-01 -e 2015-06-07`.

```
[me@mapr001 dags]$ airflow backfill tutorial -s 2015-06-01 -e 2015-06-07
[2018-07-20 14:34:29,868] {__init__.py:45} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2018-07-20 14:34:29,917] {models.py:189} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/me/airflow/dags
[2018-07-20 14:34:30,659] {models.py:1197} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: tutorial.print_date 2015-06-06 00:00:00 [scheduled]>
[2018-07-20 14:34:30,664] {base_executor.py:49} INFO - Adding to queue: airflow run tutorial print_date 2015-06-06T00:00:00 --local -sd DAGS_FOLDER/tutorial.py
......
[2018-07-20 14:34:30,806] {models.py:1190} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: tutorial.templated 2015-06-01 00:00:00 [scheduled]>, dependency 'Trigger Rule' FAILED: Task's trigger rule 'all_success' requires all upstream tasks to have succeeded, but found 1 non-success(es). upstream_tasks_state={'skipped': 0, 'successes': 0, 'failed': 0, 'upstream_failed': 0, 'done': 0, 'total': 1}, upstream_task_ids=['print_date']
[2018-07-20 14:34:30,815] {models.py:1190} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: tutorial.templated 2015-06-03 00:00:00 [scheduled]>, dependency 'Trigger Rule' FAILED: Task's trigger rule 'all_success' requires all upstream tasks to have succeeded, but found 1 non-success(es). upstream_tasks_state={'skipped': 0, 'successes': 0, 'failed': 0, 'upstream_failed': 0, 'done': 0, 'total': 1}, upstream_task_ids=['print_date']
......
```

This seems to indicate something not good (https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules), yet the backfill appears to end successfully in the terminal and web UI.

So my question is: what is going on here? Is this normal behavior (eg. the 'templated' tasks checked if it could run, saw that the 'print_date' task was not done, so just waited)? Is this explained outright somewhere in the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. 
Best explanation I found is in the source code of [models.py](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/models.py#L1305)

> Returns whether or not all the conditions are met for this task instance to be run
>           given the context for the dependencies (e.g. a task instance being force run from
>           the UI will ignore some dependencies).

Maybe this might help you too from:
[airflow.readthedocs on scheduling](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scheduler.html?highlight=Dependencies)

> The Airflow scheduler monitors all tasks and all DAGs, and triggers the task instances whose dependencies have been met. Behind the scenes, it monitors and stays in sync with a folder for all DAG objects it may contain, **and periodically (every minute or so) inspects active tasks to see whether they can be triggered.**

Or this [airflow.readthedocs FAQ](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=Dependencies)